# How to calculate the difference of a specific term inside a for loop in each iteration with the previous iteration?

Tags: java

Here i am calculating the value of Pi using Gregory-Leibniz series which is an infinite series.**I want to calculate the value of pi in each iteration of for loop and compare is to the previous iteration so i can calculate the difference.**  **Further i want to stop the iteration when the difference is less than or equal to 0.001 .** How to do it???Please help me.

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.lang.Math;
  class ValueOfPi{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double currentTerm = 0;
    double pi = 0.0;
    int odd = 1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of terms:");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1;i<=x;i++) {
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            currentTerm = (double) -4/odd;
        }
        else {
            currentTerm = (double) 4/odd;
        }

        odd=odd+2;
        pi=pi+currentTerm;
        
        
    }
    System.out.println("The value of pi:"+pi);
  }
}
```

Comment: Store the value of previous iteration in a variable. And then you can compare it with the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a variable(here: previous_pi) from the past calculation and compare it with the new calculation of pi.

```
double currentTerm = 0;
    double pi = 0.0;
    double previous_pi = 0.0;
    int odd = 1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of terms:");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1;i<=x;i++) {
        previous_pi = pi;
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            currentTerm = (double) -4/odd;
        }
        else {
            currentTerm = (double) 4/odd;
        }

        odd=odd+2;
        pi=pi+currentTerm;

        //Find the difference from the previous calculation of pi
        System.out.println("Difference from previous calculation: " + Math.abs(pi-previous_pi));

        //Stop the iteration when the difference is less than or equal to 0.001
        if(Math.abs(pi - previous_pi) <= 0.001){
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The value of pi:"+pi);
}
```